# Concat operation messes with string order of result

Tags: php

I'm trying to concatenate two variables - one is a string, the other one is a string out of numbers. The result of the concatenation should be used as ID of a div.

No matter how I order the variables inside of my concat function, the string with the number always comes first in the result.

```
    <?php $no = the_field('muralno');?>
    <?php $go = "slider-counter";?>
    <?php $item = "{$go}{$no}"; echo "$item" ?>

    <?php echo "<div id='$item' class='slider-counter'></div>"; ?>
```

Expected result is "slider-counter003".

Actual output is "003slider-counter".

EDIT:

Solution:
Problem was the function the_field(). It's part of Advanced Custom Fields plug-in for wordpress. get_field() is an alternative version and works in this case.

```
    <?php 
    $no = get_field('muralno');
    $item = "slider-counter". $no; 

    echo "<div id='".$item."' class='slider-counter'></div>"; 

    endif; ?>
```

Thanks to @lovelace

Comment: Why are you closing PHP tags and opening them again and again? Why not just open one tag and the continue?

Comment: running your code with a hardcoded `$no` set to `"003"`, it yields the expected result `"slider-counter003"` [3V4L](https://3v4l.org/44OHE). Can you show the function `the_field()`

Comment: @lovelace
Thanks, I've tried it with a hardcoded "003" too and it worked fine as well - I have no clue why though. the_field() is a function of the wordpress plug-in "advanced custom fields". Basically it reads the value of an input field in the "new post" section of the backend and gives it out as a string. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: @lovelace Thank you again! It worked now! It indeed was the function. I've changed it to "get_field()", which is mentioned in www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field

Comment: great, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't close and open PHP tags in every line.

```php
<?php  // start writing php
$no = the_field('muralno');
$go = "slider-counter";
$item = $go . $no; // use dot for concatination
echo "<div id='".$item."' class='slider-counter'>".$item."</div>"; 
?> // end writing php.
```

Also, use `.` for concatination in PHP. An example would be

```php
$first = "hello";
$second = ", World";
echo $first . $second; // hello, World
```

Third thing, is using quotes. For example

```php
$name = " John Doe";
echo "hello ".$name.""; // hello John Doe
```

Basically, we are just entering string mode then getting out of it

```php
$variable = " a string ".some valid php here." continue string ";
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the code without all the php tags. I've tried 
$item = "slider-counter". $no; 
but got the same result as before.